# Return Stringbuilder when using variable name to create string builder

Tags: loops, groovy, stringbuilder

trying to return string builder in a loop. is this workable.. I am collecting a list with `each()`, then appending 'it' to "scriptBldr_" to create a different object name each time to hold the string. then I collect the object names in a list. And trying to return using a for loop for each object name. But it's failing.

```
      List.each {
        String builderstring = "scriptBldr_" + it.replaceAll (/"/, '')
        StringBuilder $builderstring = StringBuilder.newInstance()
        if (ValidUDA == "Region") {
          $builderstring <<""" 
          XYZCode
          """
            StringBuilders.add(builderstring)
        }
      }
      for(item in StringBuilders)
      {
        return item
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following code does what you intended to code:

```
def myList = ['Hello "World"', 'asb"r"sd']
def ValidUDA = "Region"
def builders = [:]
myList.each {
    String builderstring = "scriptBldr_" + it.replaceAll (/"/, '')
    builders[builderstring] = StringBuilder.newInstance()
    if (ValidUDA == "Region") {
        builders[builderstring] <<""" 
        XYZCode
        """
    }
}
return builders
```

A `return` statement will immediatly return from the method and hence will exit the loop and only called once. So, I guess, what you wanted to achieve is to return a list of StrinngBuilders.

some hints:

- it is unusual in Groovy to start a variable with `$` and you can run into problems with such a naming
- when asking a question on SO, try to come up with a working example. As you can see, you example was missing some definitions

Update: as you've stated in you comment that you tryed to create dynamic variable names, I've updated the code to use maps. The returned map now contains the `StringBuilders` together with their names.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tips. I have set up all the definitions and the code is working. What I am trying to achieve is run the codes in parallel. I have built the separate code that I need into separate string builder objects. The dollar is to get the value of the string variable I have defined earlier, so that there's a dynamic generation of string builder objects when each member from the list is passed. Now I want to run these in parallel. hence why I am collecting the names of dynamically generated string builder objects and trying to call them in a 'for' loop.

Comment: Think the $ thing was not right.. I guess that's what is going wrong. Is there a way to dynamically build string names from members in the list?

Comment: yes, you can use dynamic variables but you should use maps for readability... let me update the code...

Comment: now, the code is still missing the parallel execution of the `.toString()`as I understand..., correct? I guess you should take a look at GPars for doing so: http://www.gpars.org

Comment: Thanks for the replies rdmueller. Cant use gpars since I am working on a oracle product that gives groovy as an option to write rules. I can't import anything new. I will test out the dynamic variables and let you know. Appreciate the help... :)

Comment: I get this error ..Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#leftShift(groovy.lang.GString)... Plus have a question when return builders is called, what happens.. it runs the code in each map element one after another?

Comment: the example above works for me. It seems that you use different inputs and get the error. Which inputs do you use?